# What word, in the a casual conversation would be equivalent to the word “deal breaker”?

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for a synonym of deal breaker but it should be used in a casual conversation because the word, "deal breaker" is often used in transactional or business setting.

I am looking for a equivalent word which precisely means "this conversation wouldn't last long".

Comment: How does “deal breaker” mean “this conversation wouldn’t last long???

Comment: I also don’t see why “deal breaker” can’t be used in casual conversation.  Dude, you ought to ask her out.  No way. She smokes. That’s a deal breaker.

Comment: I think OP is looking to describe the event that takes place in a casual conversation, not describe the even in a casual conversation. Yes, @Sushant19?

Answer (score 1):

It's a common cliche used (and over-used) in casual conversation.

It's hyphenated: *deal-breaker*.

Answer (score -2):

I might describe the conversation as "[abortive](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/abortive)" or even "[stillborn](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/stillborn)."